# Unable to delete a file that I am able to see and rename, showing file not found error on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-management, file-permissions

**I am unbale to delete a folder 'abc' neither it's inside folder 'history'. It shows 'Item not found' error.**

However, if i try to rename these files, I am able to do so.

Moreover, even if i shred it with Bitdefender(My antivirus), it is unable to do so showing the file not found error.

Also, upon scanning, it doesn't detect anything malicious and shows it as safe.

I tried running **chkdsk /f**, but got:

```
Access Denied as you do not have sufficient privileges or
the disk may be locked by another process.
You have to invoke this utility running in elevated mode
and make sure the disk is unlocked.
```

I think the problem is with the inside folder: "History" which is an empty folder. I am able to enter abc directory but unable to enter History:

```
D:\abc>cd History
The system cannot find the path specified.

D:\abc>dir
 Volume in drive D is DATA
 Volume Serial Number is 2E98-37AA

 Directory of D:\abc

19-09-2021  20:47    <DIR>          .
19-09-2021  20:47    <DIR>          ..
19-09-2021  20:47    <DIR>          History
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  546,097,836,032 bytes free

D:\abc>cd ..

D:\>rmdir /s abc
abc, Are you sure (Y/N)? Y
abc\History  - The system cannot find the file specified.
```

**What should I do to delete this file?** It's lies in disk: D

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: u mean restarting pc r8? yes, I have :(, infact I have even kept my windows updated to latest...